# Stripe subscriptions and Rails 4: No route matches [POST] "/subscriptions" when new user tries to buy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, stripe-payments, subscriptions

I'm adding subscription purchases to an existing Rails 4 app, we use Devise. This is following the Mastering Modern Payments approach.

I can successfully create a plan from my rails console (with an id of 1) and have it appear in Stripe. So I know the basic handshake is ok.

As a user when I go to the payment page and fill out all the info and click submit I get the error: Routing Error: No route matches [POST] "/subscriptions".

User pay page I am trying to buy on is at
localhost:3000/subscriptions/new?plan_id=1

It looks like this:
subscriptions/new.html.erb

```
<% unless @subscription.errors.blank? %>
    <%= @subscription.errors.full_messages.to_sentence %>
<% end %>

<h2>Subscribing to <%= @plan.name %></h2>

<%= form_for @subscription, html: { id: 'payment-form' } do |f| %>
    <input type="hidden" name="plan_id" value="<%= @plan.id %>" />
    <span class="payment-errors"></span>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Email Address</span>
        <input type="email" size="20" name="email_address"/>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Card Number</span>
        <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>CVC</span>
        <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>
        <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
      </label>
      <span> / </span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Pay Now</button>
<% end %>
```

We have these routes:

```
Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url      
Path Match
subscriptions_index_path    GET /subscriptions/index(.:format)  subscriptions#index
subscriptions_new_path  GET /subscriptions/new(.:format)    subscriptions#new
subscriptions_create_path   GET /subscriptions/create(.:format) subscriptions#create
subscriptions_show_path GET /subscriptions/show(.:format)   subscriptions#show
subscriptions_plans_path    GET /subscriptions/plans(.:format)  subscriptions#plans
subscriptions_update_path   GET /subscriptions/update(.:format) subscriptions#update
subscriptions_destroy_path  GET /subscriptions/destroy(.:format)    subscriptions#destroy
plans_index_path    GET /plans/index(.:format)  plans#index
plans_show_path GET /plans/show(.:format)   plans#show
stripe_checkout_path    POST    /stripe_checkout(.:format)  subscription#stripe_checkout
subscription_checkout_path  POST    /subscription_checkout(.:format)    subscription#subscription_checkout
new_user_session_path   GET /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#new
user_session_path   POST    /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session_path   DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)   devise/sessions#destroy
user_password_path  POST    /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#create
new_user_password_path  GET /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password_path GET /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
PATCH   /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#update
PUT /users/password(.:format)   devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration_path   GET /users/cancel(.:format) users#cancel
user_registration_path  POST    /users(.:format)    users#create
new_user_registration_path  GET /users/sign_up(.:format)    users#new
edit_user_registration_path GET /users/edit(.:format)   users#edit
PATCH   /users(.:format)    users#update
PUT /users(.:format)    users#update
DELETE  /users(.:format)    users#destroy
accept_user_invitation_path GET /users/invitation/accept(.:format)  devise/invitations#edit
remove_user_invitation_path GET /users/invitation/remove(.:format)  devise/invitations#destroy
user_invitation_path    POST    /users/invitation(.:format) devise/invitations#create
new_user_invitation_path    GET /users/invitation/new(.:format) devise/invitations#new
PATCH   /users/invitation(.:format) devise/invitations#update
PUT /users/invitation(.:format) devise/invitations#update
users_path  GET /users(.:format)    users#index
POST    /users(.:format)    users#create
new_user_path   GET /users/new(.:format)    users#new
edit_user_path  GET /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
user_path   GET /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
PATCH   /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
PUT /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
DELETE  /users/:id(.:format)    users#destroy
entries_path    POST    /entries(.:format)  entries#create
new_entry_path  GET /entries/new(.:format)  entries#new
edit_entry_path GET /entries/:id/edit(.:format) entries#edit
entry_path  GET /entries/:id(.:format)  entries#show
PATCH   /entries/:id(.:format)  entries#update
PUT /entries/:id(.:format)  entries#update
DELETE  /entries/:id(.:format)  entries#destroy
orders_path GET /orders(.:format)   orders#index
POST    /orders(.:format)   orders#create
new_order_path  GET /orders/new(.:format)   orders#new
edit_order_path GET /orders/:id/edit(.:format)  orders#edit
order_path  GET /orders/:id(.:format)   orders#show
PATCH   /orders/:id(.:format)   orders#update
PUT /orders/:id(.:format)   orders#update
DELETE  /orders/:id(.:format)   orders#destroy
last24_s1_events_path   GET /s1_events/last24(.:format) s1_events#last24
s1_event_subscriptions_path GET /s1_events/:s1_event_id/subscriptions(.:format) subscriptions#index
POST    /s1_events/:s1_event_id/subscriptions(.:format) subscriptions#create
new_s1_event_subscription_path  GET /s1_events/:s1_event_id/subscriptions/new(.:format) subscriptions#new
s1_events_path  GET /s1_events(.:format)    s1_events#index
upmin_path      /admin  Upmin::Engine
root_path   GET /   dashboard#index
income_path GET /income(.:format)   dashboard#income
liquidity_path  GET /liquidity(.:format)    dashboard#liquidity
time_horizon_path   GET /time-horizon(.:format) dashboard#time_horizon
get_feed_path   GET /get-feed(.:format) pages#get_feed
get_updates_path    GET /get-updates(.:format)  pages#get_updates
subscriptions_path  GET /subscriptions(.:format)    pages#subscriptions
api_path    GET /api(.:format)  pages#api
icons_path  GET /icons(.:format)    pages#icons
contact_us_path GET /contact_us(.:format)   contacts#new
s1_qa_path  GET /s1-qa(.:format)    pages#s1_qa
contacts_path   POST    /contacts(.:format) contacts#create
Routes for Upmin::Engine
root_path   GET /   upmin/models#dashboard
upmin_dashboard_path    GET /   upmin/models#dashboard
upmin_search_path   GET|POST    /m/:klass(.:format) upmin/models#search
upmin_new_model_path    GET /m/:klass/new(.:format) upmin/models#new
upmin_create_model_path POST    /m/:klass/new(.:format) upmin/models#create
upmin_model_path    GET /m/:klass/i/:id(.:format)   upmin/models#show
PUT /m/:klass/i/:id(.:format)   upmin/models#update
upmin_action_path   POST    /m/:klass/i/:id/:method(.:format)   upmin/models#action
```

And our routes.rb file looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'subscriptions/index'

  get 'subscriptions/new'

  get 'subscriptions/create'

  get 'subscriptions/show'

  get 'subscriptions/plans'

  get 'subscriptions/update'

  get 'subscriptions/destroy'

  get 'plans/index'

  get 'plans/show'

  post 'stripe_checkout' => 'subscription#stripe_checkout'
  post 'subscription_checkout' => 'subscription#subscription_checkout'


  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'users' }
  resources :users
  resources :entries, except: [:index]
  resources :orders
  resources :s1_events, only: [:index] do
    get 'last24', on: :collection
  resources :subscriptions, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  end

  mount Upmin::Engine => '/admin'

  root to: 'dashboard#index'
  get 'income', to: 'dashboard#income'
  get 'liquidity', to: 'dashboard#liquidity'
  get 'time-horizon', to: 'dashboard#time_horizon'
  get 'get-feed', to: 'pages#get_feed'
  get 'get-updates', to: 'pages#get_updates'
  get 'subscriptions', to: 'pages#subscriptions'
  get 'api', to: 'pages#api'
  get 'icons', to: 'pages#icons'
  get 'contact_us', to: 'contacts#new'
  get 's1-qa', to: 'pages#s1_qa'
  resources 'contacts', only: [:create]
end
```

We have a CreateSubscription service object:
create_subscription.rb

```
class CreateSubscription
  def self.call(plan, email_address, token)
    user, raw_token = CreateUser.call(email_address)

    subscription = Subscription.new(
        plan: plan,
        user: user
    )

    begin
      stripe_sub = nil
      if user.stripe_customer_id.blank?
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            source: token,
            email: user.email,
            plan: plan.stripe_id,
        )
        user.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
        user.save!
        stripe_sub = customer.subscriptions_choices.first
      else
        customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(user.stripe_customer_id)
        stripe_sub = customer.subscriptions_choices.create(
            plan: plan.stripe_id
        )
      end

      subscription.stripe_id = stripe_sub.id

      subscription.save!
    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
      subscription.errors[:base] << e.message
    end

    subscription
  end
end
```

That refers to a CreateUser service object here:
create_user.rb

```
class CreateUser
  def self.call(email_address)

    user = User.find_by(email: email_address)

    return user if user.present?

    raw_token, enc_token = Devise.token_generator.generate(
        User, :reset_password_token)
    password = SecureRandom.hex(32)

    user = User.create!(
        email: email_address,
        password: password,
        password_confirmation: password,
        reset_password_token: enc_token,
        reset_password_sent_at: Time.now
    )

    return user, raw_token
  end
end
```

The way these are supposed to work together is after Devise. Meaning, if user exists already it adds payment to that. If not, create a new user. So there should not be any issues with Devise here.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this error, and let my users buy subscriptions, are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty straight forward. You don't have a `POST /subscriptions` route.

You have a bunch of other things such as a `get 'subscriptions/create'` and a `POST /s1_events/:s1_event_id/subscriptions`.

I would suggest you start by cleaning up your routes.

## bad

```
get 'subscriptions/index'
get 'subscriptions/new'
get 'subscriptions/create'
get 'subscriptions/show'
get 'subscriptions/plans'
get 'subscriptions/update'
get 'subscriptions/destroy'
```

**Don't ever do this.** GET actions should be always be [idempotent](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html). You are also violating the Rails REST conventions:

```
GET    '/subscriptions'     => index
POST   '/subscriptions'     => create
GET    '/subscriptions/:id' => show
PATCH  '/subscriptions/:id' => update
DELETE '/subscriptions/:id' => destroy
```

And those `subscriptions/update` and destroy paths won't work unless you do `GET subscriptions/update?id=foo&bar=baz`. Yuck.

## good

```
resources :subscriptions
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Comment: Thanks max for responding. After I cleaned up the routes as you suggested, I saw that the route I needed was already in use. I've marked your answer with a check as if helped me figure this out. Cheers.